# Delphi - GLScene how to get x,y,z of a picked object

Tags: delphi, opengl, directx, glscene

I have a scene with basic geometry (pick demo) I want when I select any object to return the x,y and z of the mouse cursor otherwise return -1

Comment: Picking has been [widely discussed](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[opengl]+picking)

Comment: Voting to reopen. Seems like a real question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general OpenGL technique is to use [gluUnProject()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml) which takes screen x,y and the z-value of the depth-buffer and reverse-transforms that into world (or view) coordinates.

> gluUnProject maps the specified window coordinates into object
>   coordinates using model, proj, and view. The result is stored in objX,
>   objY, and objZ. A return value of GLU_TRUE indicates success; a return
>   value of GLU_FALSE indicates failure.

See [NeHe's tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/using_gluunproject/16013/) on how to use it in a general OpenGL app. It should hopefully get you started in the right direction with your Delphi app.